# how to apply Generics for the method which is not using type parameter of the class

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to Java Generics. I'm designing my DAO layer. I'm using JPA with Spring. I have a BaseDAO which is extended by all other DAO classes.

```
public abstract class BaseDAO<E, Id extends Serializable> implements IBaseDAO<E, Id> {

private Class<E> entityClass;

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return entityManager;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public BaseDAO() {
    ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass()
            .getGenericSuperclass();
    this.entityClass = (Class<E>) genericSuperclass
            .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

@Override
public E create(E entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
    return entity;
}

//Some more methods

@Override
public List<?> executeNativeQuery(String queryString,
        Map<String, Object> param) {

//implementation goes here

    return resultList;
}

}
```

I've problem in adding public List executeNativeQuery(String queryString,
            Map param)  to this class. Because if I've to use this method in my class A which extends BaseDAO, i will have to specify the type parameter 'E' and 'Id' for Base Class. Ideally, type parameter should have been the entity class on which we're going to make the db call. But since this method is native query method, i don't use entity class as such. How can i handle such scenario ?

Edit:
Suppose below is the DAO class which extends BaseDAO and uses executeNativeQuery method

public class MyDAO extends BaseDAO{

```
public String myMethod(){

String query="select a1,a2,a3,b4 from A a, B b where a.pk=b.pk";
...
..
List<String> = executeNativeQuery(query, map, String.class);

...
..  
}
```

}

I will still get below error if i don't specify the type parameter for BaseDAO.

java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)

What should be the type parameter which should be passed for BaseDAO ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do as the following.

```
@Override
public <T> List<T> executeNativeQuery(String queryString,
        Map<String, Object> param, Class<T> clazz) {

//implementation goes here

    return resultList;
}
```

In the third parameter you can specify the type of the list to work with. E. g. `List<SomeEntity> result = executeNativeQuery("query", paramMap, SomeEntity.class)`.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, the problem is in the constructor in the following line.

```
ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
```

You should use `getGenericInterfaces()[0]` instead, because the `BaseDAO` class does not extend from anything (therefore you get `Object` as the parent) but implements `IBaseDAO`.